# Fluent Migration: How to add and/or clause to delete/update statement

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I started using fluent migration and started to wonder how to perform deletes or updates using where clauses.

As far as the simple things go, it's pretty straightforward. As per the Fluent Migration wiki (https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/fluent-interface.html#data-expressions), here is a simple delete with a where clause:

```
Delete.FromTable("Users").Row(new { FirstName = "John" }); 

// Resulting sql:
// delete from Users where FirstName = 'John';
```

Then you could expand this to be more specific, like this:

```
Delete.FromTable("Users").Row(new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });

// Resulting sql:
// delete from Users where FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Smith';
```

My question is, how do I specify an OR expression? I would want my resulting sql to be like this:

```
delete from Users where FirstName = 'John' or LastName = 'Smith';
```

I can't find any examples online or in their wiki, even when looking at the interface directly.

Comment: So far I've found you can add more .Row statements to create separate delete statements entirely. .Row(new { FirstName = "John" }).Row(new {LastName = "Smith"}); results in "delete from Users where FirstName = 'John'; delete from Users where LastName = 'Smith'; What would I do for "Like" expressions, or more complicated or/and clauses, or math functions like <, >, etc?

Comment: Consider just `Execute.Sql` when it comes to more complicated queries. As long as an engine supports the sql92 you still should be able to target it.

Comment: The site you linked has syntax charts for the methods, and there is no `or` capability listed; nor anything more complicated than equals testing.

Comment: I noticed that too where I looked. Was wondering if there was something I missed